# Set Property of a Control on a Different State? - Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, logic, flash-builder

I'm having trouble setting the property of a control on another state.

**Latest_News_Display** is under the **Latest_News** state. I want to set **Latest_News_Display**'s **x** property even if the **currentState** is set to **Intro**. However, when I try to use **Latest_News.Latest_News_Display.x = 10**,it returns an error that says **1120: Access of undefined property Latest_News**. So how do I go about doing it?

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo in your post, but if `Latest_News_Display` is your object, `x` the property you want to set, and `Latest_News` the state you want to set it in, the syntax should be `Latest_News_Display.x.Latest_News = 10`, ie. `object.property.state = value`.  Your post currently has `state.object.property = value`, which unless you extended the State class, that doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Hmmm I just got used to that model where MainObject.SubObject.Property from previous IDEs that I've used...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee a component in another state has been created at the time you are trying to set it.  It's hard to say for sure without seeing your code, but I'm guessing that is the issue based on your error.

You'll, basically, have to create your own method of deferred value setting.  So, when you try to set it do something like this:

```
if(Latest_News_Display){
 Latest_News_Display.x = 10
} else {
 cachedLatest_News_DisplayX = 10
}
```

Then listen to the [currentStateChange event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#event%3acurrentStateChange) and set the new value then:

```
protected function onCurrentStateChange(event:StateChangeEvent):void{    
Latest_News_Display.x = cachedLatest_News_DisplayX 
}
```

I'll also add that, based on the bolded items in your question that it appears you are trying to access a state by name Latest_News.  If you create a local variable pointed at a specific state, you can do this.  But, if you're using MXML then you probably didn't.  Even so, a state is just, basically, an array of overrides you wouldn't be able to access components in that state directly.

Comment: Here's the thing, I need to set the x value of Latest_News_Display so that when the state changes to Latest_News, it will be on its initial position then it will move back to where it's supposed to be placed as the effects go on. That was my plan.

Comment: Without seeing a code sample or screenshot or a running app, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  In the Flextras Calendar, to place and size things properly on "non visible" states, I had to extend a bunch of the state override classes to expose private properties and I also had to render the 'invisible' states in the background.  It took a lot of time (>1 month) and was probably not worth it.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tip I guess I'll have to use some other method than transitions...

Comment: @Shedo Chung-Hee Surashu Nothing in your post mentioned anything about transitions.  States are not the same as transitions, although you can create transitions when the app changes between states.  IF you want to elaboarate, or provide sample code or screenshots or a running app demonstrating your issue, please do.